# .NET Windows Forms - Click event on DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I have a `DateTimePicker` in my Windows Forms application. I gave it a custom format so that, when the form loads, the `DateTimePicker` appears with a blank value, and made a handler for the picker's `ValueChanged` event so that it changes its format when the user clicks the icon to show the calendar.

However, I want to set my `DateTimePicker` so that it changes its format when the user clicks on the blank part (the one that would contain the date in the specified format). This is my code for the event:

```
Private Sub dtpDateOfBirth_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
    dtpDateOfBirth.Click

    Console.WriteLine("dtpDateOfBirth Click")
    dtpDateOfBirth.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
End Sub
```

but it doesn't seem to be doing anything, not even when I click the icon that shows the calendar.

**How can I change the format of my `DateTimePicker` through a mouse click?**

Comment: If you look at the dropdown list  in the code editor the DTP doesnt expose a click event.  The user would not really expect the format to change on a click anyway

Comment: @Plutonix Actually, it does expose a click event; I clicked on it and it made the Sub for me. That's why I'm asking this question. And the user who tested it actually requested for this; it's not exactly a format change for him, though; the custom format is a space, so the date appears blank at first, and he expected to be able to type after clicking on the blank part, without being forced to use the calendar.

Comment: [actually it does not](http://i.imgur.com/yt67mxy.jpg)  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) The click events are... `not intended to be used directly from your code.`

Comment: @Plutonix Ohhhh... You meant in the Properties. I thought you meant the bar above the code, where you pick a control and an event, and it automatically edits the code to add the handler. Sorry.

Comment: The Property pane will show Events or Properties: that was the Event view.  None of the Click related events show in the code window drop down either - or are not supposed to.  Might be something odd with VS2015 if you see one.  Mine wont compile `Handles dtp.Click` because there is no such thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Mousedown event:

```
Private Sub dtpDateOfBirth_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
    dtpDateOfBirth.MouseDown

    Console.WriteLine("dtpDateOfBirth Click")
    dtpDateOfBirth.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
End Sub
```